# How to calculate this integral using residue theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f,g$ are holomorphic in $D(0,1)$. $P_1,P_2,...,P_k$ are roots of $f$ in $D(0,1)$. their orders are $n_1,...,n_k$. Compute $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\cdot g(z)dz.$$

Using residue theorem I have
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\cdot g(z)dz=\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{(n_j-1)!}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^{n_j-1}\left[(z-P_j)^{n_j}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}g(z)\right]_{z=P_j}.
$$

But someone says 
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\cdot g(z)dz=\sum_{j=1}^kn_jg(P_j).
$$
I don't know how to get it. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Have you actually tried taking the derivative in your formula?

Comment: Can I suggest you to give an _on topic_ title to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [the argument principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle#Applications_and_consequences):
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\cdot g(z)dz=\sum_{\mbox{zeroes of } f}n(\gamma,a)g(a)-\sum_{\mbox{poles of } f}n(\gamma,b)g(b)=\sum_{j=1}^kn_jg(P_j)$$

Comment: Thank you very much, @Dennis. Your answer and link are very helpful.